# Axiom of Extensionality - Why not called equality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

Axiom of Extensionality, I understand that if two sets have exactly the same members they are equal. However why it is called Extensionality? Why not equality?

Comment: I also wonder about this, since it seems to me that the axiom of extensionality is there to define "what equality is for sets", instead of what a set is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Extension" refers to a set being defined by its content, as opposed to "intension" which is a term to say it is defined by some form of specification.

Let $A = \{x \text{ in } \mathbb{R} \text{ such that} -1 \leq x \leq +1\}$

Let $B = \{y \text{ in } \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } y = \sin(x) \text{ for some } x \text{ in } \mathbb{R}\}$.

The sets have different intensions (specifications), but contain the same elements and therefore have the same extensions. So (according to the "Axiom of Extension") $A = B$.

Comment: OK. My understanding as a layman. <Begin>Element x is present in A. Element X is present in B. "Extension means" the very presence of x in another set B, Not just only in A.<End> I understand the specification: The set of students in Music Class "can be" the same for another Drawing class. However the purpose of the class is Drawing, rather than music. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A (much) fuller explanation of extension and intension can be found at http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intensional/

Comment: Quoting from the SEP link above "The two phrases, “morning star” and “evening star” may designate the same object, but they do not have the same meaning. **Meanings, in this sense, are often called intensions, and things designated, extensions.**". Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Because it says a set is determined by its **extension**.

Comment: Thanks. When we say, set A = set B, what is extension here? The elements of A belonging to another set as well is what we mean by extension?