# Can this rule of inference do replace axiom of extensionality?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory, natural-deduction, alternative-set-theories

If I replace the below axiom in [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) (or [NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory)) by the below inference rule, there are any consequence in *what* can be demonstrated?

**Axiom:** If two sets (or classes) have the same elements then their are equal.
$$
\forall{ }A\forall{ }B(\forall{ }x((x\in A) \Leftrightarrow (x\in B))\Rightarrow A = B)
$$

**Inference Rule:** From $\varphi(A)$ and $\forall{ }x((x\in A) \Leftrightarrow (x\in B))$ infers $\varphi(B)$.
$$
\{\varphi(A), \forall{ }x((x\in A) \Leftrightarrow (x\in B))\} \vdash \varphi(B)
$$

##### Comment

This substitution is based on Leibniz Law (but different of [this Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/442683/1040324) do not quantify about predicates). This substitution have three motives:

1. Play with logic.
2. Remove the equality symbol.
3. Remove the axiom (I like natural deduction, when possible): I imagine that this "formalism" have special significance for classes, since a class is *defined* by the logical property of their elements then one can imagine that the extension (see [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/672250/1040324)) is "not a truth" but only a "program" to perform a proof (see [this Math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2860854/1040324)).

Comment: I think it might even be sufficient to use the special case $\forall A \forall B (\forall x (x\in A \leftrightarrow x \in B)) \rightarrow (\forall x (A \in x \leftrightarrow B \in x))$ as a replacement for the axiom.  From there, you should be able to prove your inference rule for general $\varphi$ by structural induction (as a metatheorem).

Comment: In both the axiom and the rule, & was presumably nintended to be $\leftrightarrow$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The OP said in motive #2 that he wants to avoid the equality symbol.

Comment: I think that in ZF or ZFC you could replace every instance of $x=y$ with $\forall z\, (z\in x\iff z\in y)$. It would be very cumbersome but apparently equivalent..... My edit was for spelling (bellow/below). Awl Inglish spelling iz broken and needz reepair.